# Override the default tab autocomplete content in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

What's the correct way to override the JavaScript "fun" tab completion for example?

I've created a new file in my user package called: `my.sublime-completions` and I understand that file requires two properties (`scope` & `completions`)?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation on completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) and the two ***`See Also`*** links at the top should provide plenty of detail on how to structure your `.sublime-completions` file for use in JavaScript. For example, the following exactly replicates the default snippet (use `\n` for newlines and `\t` for tabs, if needed):

```json
{
        "scope": "source.js",

        "completions":
        [
                { "trigger": "fun", "contents": "function ${1:function_name} (${2:argument}) {\n    ${0:// body...}\n}" }
        ]
}
```

The easiest way to override the default `fun` JavaScript snippet is to first install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/). Once that's set up, restart Sublime and open the Command Palette with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Linux). Type `prv` to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options, and choose `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`. Scroll down the list and select `JavaScript`, then open the `function-(fun).sublime-snippet` file, using XML for syntax highlighting if you wish. If you are using a more recent version of Sublime, the file may be located under `JavaScript/Snippets`.

Next, set the contents of the file to the following:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>fun</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>Don't Use</description>
</snippet>
```

Save the file, and you should be all set. Assuming your `.sublime-completions` file is set up correctly, when you type `fun` in a JS file you should only see your completion, not the default one.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'd totally missed that 'See Also' link!

Comment: Correct, though I'd recommend using "PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource" to only edit the files one needs (they automatically save to the correct location). That way, you you still allow updates outside of your custom completions and have fewer duplicated files.